# Magento allow to create 2 account from an email?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, email-validation

I got an issue like this. At first, I create a member account by admin with an email. Then, I used that email to sign up another account and I got these result:

```
entity_id | username  | email            | website      | store_id
287       | tester123 | tester123@tk.com | Main Website | 1
286       | tester123 | tester123@tk.com | Admin        | 0
```

When I login in the Index page, I must login by the account entity_id 287, I could not login with the account 286.
I want to know the reason why Magento allow to create 2 different accounts with only an email. And I want to find out the code which valid this situation.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento allow/support multiple site/multiple store and having index of combination of email+website_id. So it treat that same mail id for different site. if you will create new website with same name 'Admin' and it's store_id as 0 than you will be able to login on that site/store with entity_id 286.

Currently your site/store is main website/1 so you get logged in though entity_id 287

Comment: But both of 2 accounts which I created are the customer and get the group name is "Registered Member". I think both of them must be able to used in the main site as a customer, mustn't them?

Comment: Thanks. I got it. You can show me the code/files which validate this situation?

Comment: go to app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Session.php and check the login function, here it set the website id before customer authenticate.